# Propriedade dinâmica em classe static

Tags: c#

Possuo uma classe estática e nela tenho um método também `static`. O método retorna um valor que está em cache, entretanto essa `Key`, ela tem o valor dinâmico:

```
key = User.Identity.GetUserName();
public static class MeuHelper {

   public static string Get {
      get {
         return cache.Get(key);
      }
   }
}
```

Como eu poderia declarar essa propriedade `KEY`?

Eu tentei as seguintes declarações

```
public static string Key = User.Identity.GetUserName();
public static string Key {
 get {
    return User.Identity.GetUserName();
 }
}
```

E até mesmo:

```
public static string Key {Get;set;}
```

No construtor:

```
static MeuHelper {
   Key = User.Identity.GetUserName();
}
```

Quando vou *debugar*, faço da seguinte maneira:

Logo com um usuário no navegador, e em outra aba anônima, logo com outro usuário, entretanto sempre prevalece o valor do primeiro usuário.

---

#### Edição:

O *helper* é para utilização de cache. O mesmo deve ter uma key para cada usuário logado, por esse motivo utilizo o nome de usuário, que é único por usuário.

Logo a ideia é ter a *key* em `String`, a qual sempre irá retornar o `username` do usuário logado.

Comment: Qual o tipo de `cache`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o cache é redis, o mesmo deve ter uma key unica para cada sessão de usuário, por isso utilizar o UserName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira mais elegante de fazer o que você quer seria criar um método de extensão para [`IPrincipal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `User` implementa `IPrincipal`:

```
public static class UserExtensions 
{
    private static Object threadLock = new Object();

    public static String RedisIdentifier(this IPrincipal User) 
    {
        lock (threadLock)
        {
            return cache.Get(User.Identity.GetUserName());
        }
    }
}
```

Já fiz *thread-safe* pra evitar quaisquer problemas de concorrência na sua aplicação.

Answer (score -1):

Como falaste em navegador, vou assumir que estás a desenvolver uma aplicação web.

Nesse caso, a resposta é: **não** usar estado estático mutavel!

Usar estado estático numa aplicação web é receita para desastre. Em qualquer momento, o servidor pode estar a servir `n` pedidos simultaneamente, em que todos eles acedem a variáveis partilhadas, e é  difícil sincronizar correctamente o acesso a essas variáveis.

O único caso "aceitável" para usar estado estático é quando se trata de estado read-only, imutável, ou quando esse estado realmente precisa de ser partilhado por todos os pedidos (como o exemplo da cache).

---

Dito isto, acho que deves transformar a propriedade `Get` num método `GetCacheItem` (assumindo que a instância `cache` é thread-safe ou que o acesso a ela é devidamente sincronizado)

```
public static class MeuHelper
{
   public static string GetCacheItem(string key)
   {
       return cache.Get(key);
   }

   public static string GetCacheItemForUser(IPrincipal user)
   {
       return GetCacheItem(user.Identity.GetUsername());
   }
}
```

Cada pedido deverá chamar o método e passar a sua própria key:

```
var item = MeuHelper.GetCacheItemForUser(User);
```

Comment: a ideia de criar-se helper class é não se repetir código, entretanto apesar da sua implementação resolver, acaba-se por repetir muito a chamada de User.Identity =/

Comment: @Rod Eu concordo com a ideia de encapsular codigo repetido, mas esse encapsulamento não tem (e nao deve) de ser estático. Actualizei o exemplo, para demonstrar como encapsular código repetido sem criar estado estático

Comment: Porque o downvote?